# Suggest some best Practices for Redis DB snapshot

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I am currently hosting the Redis OSS in clustered mode and having the RDB + AOF as backup mechanism.

While this is working fine for us, want to know is it a good advice to keep Save 900 1 in the setup as RDB snapshot mechanism, with this we are getting some latencies which the snapshot process is taking because it is doing COW(copy on write)
[image]

Or is it advisable to configure the BGSAVE at non-critical or less traffic hours via cron job. With that approach what are the downside, does the COW will take lot of memory ?

Answer (score 2):

If your memory usage is high (more than 70%) configuring `BGSAVE 900 1` might not be a very good idea because `BGSAVE` requires Redis to fork and create a child process that takes care of dumping the data to the `RDB file`.

When the amount of data that you are storing is few GBs, `BGSAVE` can be a good and safe solution as it will complete in few seconds. But when data footprint is high and you don't have much free memory available, `BGSAVE` can cause system to pause for several seconds or can cause heavy use of system virtual memory which can degrade Redis performance. The extent of pausing will depend on the hardware. Real hardwares roughly allows us to create a fork of Redis process at around 10ms per GB of memory that Redis is using. But with Xen Virtualized machines (like AWS EC2 instances) takes aroun 200ms per GB of time to fork.

To prevent this, one solution can be as you said to disable automatic `BGSAVE` and execute `BGSAVE` manually through cron job at time where traffic is less. You can also use SAVE instead of `BGSAVE`. With `SAVE`, Redis blocks until `SAVE` is completed but does not fork, so there is no fork delay. In your application, if you have any window where you know there might not be much read and writes, using `SAVE` might be better as it is much faster than `BGSAVE` (be careful though, during this period clients will not be able to read/write to Redis).

Another solution could be, since you have a cluster where there might be replicas to the master, disable the `BGSAVE` from master and enable it only in replicas. This way, your master is not burdended with `BGSAVE` and your writes will not be impacted.

One more solution could be, since you have `AOF` enabled, you can disable `BGSAVE` completely.

There can be mutiple ways to implement it depending on what is feasible and considering the trade-off

Comment: Thank you Ankit for sharing the insights. I liked the idea of doing BGSAVE from replicas. As this is a clustered redis and the replica can be promoted to master at any point of time. please suggest how to deal in that scenario.